# Why does my site reload after clicking edit, but before saving the changes?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So i have a pretty basic site, where you can add blog posts with a title, author and content. The posts also get two buttons - a delete and an edit button. Both buttons, and adding the posts to the html adds/deletes/edits the chosen posts in a .json file too, trough a local json server. Everything works fine except one - when i click the edit button in one of the sites it should give 2 new button to the form, and fill the form with the posts values. Except, when i click on edit, i can see for a second the two new buttons in the form is added (save and cancel) but in just a blink it also reloads the whole site, preventing me from editing the posts with the button.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/yeti/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6baa217c17.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
 <title>Washington Post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
            <i class="fas fa-book-open text-primary"></i>My<span class="text-primary">Blog</span></h1>
            <form action="" id="book-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="author">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div id="btn-container">
                    <button id="add-post-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Post</button>
                </div>

                <!-- POSTS -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="post-container" class="col">

                    </div>
                </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript code

```
//Fő változók

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/posts";
const postContainer = document.getElementById("post-container");
const addPostBtn = document.getElementById("add-post-button");

//input mezők
const titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
const contentInput = document.getElementById("content");
const authorInput = document.getElementById("author");
const typeInput = document.getElementById("type");

//eventlisteners
addPostBtn.addEventListener("click", addPost);
postContainer.addEventListener("click", editOrDelete);

//függvények
function loadPosts(){
    fetch(baseUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            json.forEach(element => {
                postContainer.appendChild(generatePostElement(element));
            });
        });   
};

function generatePostElement(object) {

    let postElement = document.createElement("div");
    postElement.id = `post-${object.id}`;
    postElement.classList = "card mt-5";

    postElement.innerHTML = `<div class="p-5">
                                    <h1>${object.title}</h1>
                                    <span>${object.content}</span>
                                    <blockquote>${object.author}</blockquote>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete" id-to-delete="${object.id}">Delete</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm edit" id-to-edit="${object.id}">Edit</button>
                                </div>`;
    return postElement;
};

function addPost(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let newPostObject = {
        title: titleInput.value,
        author: authorInput.value,
        content: contentInput.value
    };

    fetch(baseUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newPostObject)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            resetForm();
            postContainer.appendChild(generatePostElement(json));
        });
};

function editOrDelete(e){
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("id-to-delete")) {
        deletePost(e.target.getAttribute("id-to-delete"));
    } else if (e.target.hasAttribute("id-to-edit")){
        prepareEditPost(e.target.getAttribute("id-to-edit"));        
    } else {
        console.log("egyik sem");        
    }
};

function deletePost(id) {
    let deleteUrl = `${baseUrl}/${id}`;
    fetch(deleteUrl, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
        .then(res => console.log("Post " + id + " deleted"))
        .then(res => {
            document.getElementById(`post-${id}`).remove();
        });  
};

function prepareEditPost(id) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.getElementById("btn-container").innerHTML = `
            <button id="edit-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id-to-edit="${id}">Save</button>
            <button id="reset-btn" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cancel</button>`;
    let editBtn = document.getElementById("edit-btn");
    let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");

    editBtn.addEventListener("click", editPost);
    resetBtn.addEventListener("click", resetForm);

    let postUrl = `${baseUrl}/${id}`;

    fetch(postUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            //console.log(json);
            titleInput.value = json.title;
            contentInput.value = json.content;
            authorInput.value = json.author;
        })
};

function editPost(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let editPostObject = {
        title: titleInput.value,
        content: contentInput.value,
        author: authorInput.value,
    };

    let id = e.target.getAttribute("id-to-edit");

    let editUrl = `${baseUrl}/${id}`;

    fetch(editUrl, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(editPostObject)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            resetForm();
            let HTMLElementTotEdit = document.getElementById(`post-${id}`);
            HTMLElementTotEdit.parentNode.replaceChild(generatePostElement(json), HTMLElementTotEdit);            
        });
};

function resetForm() {
    titleInput.value = "";
    contentInput.value = "";
    authorInput.value = "";
    document.getElementById("btn-container").innerHTML = `<button id="add-post-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add Post</button>
    `;
};

//kezdés
loadPosts();
```

If anyone can help me to prevent the site from reloading upon clicking the edit button that would be awesome! If anything is now clear please ask, english is not my native language.

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: You need to prevent default the form submit event, not the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you add submit button to the form and the other buttons without type="submit"

Comment: *"...and the other buttons without type="submit""* The **default** `type` on `button` is `submit`. If the other buttons are supposed to not submit, the OP needs to add `type="button"`, not leave it off. (And yes, it's an unfortunate default...)

Comment: Yayy, that was it! Thank you so much, really means a lot to me!